# Schrodinger equation of spin-singlet wave function

Tags: schroedinger-equation, superconductivity

I'm reading the book *Introduction to superconductivity* by Michael Tinkham and encountered a small math problem.

In page 44, we need to substitute the spin-singlet two electrons wave function $\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}g_k\cos k(r)(\uparrow\downarrow-\downarrow\uparrow)$ into the Schrodinger equation $[-2\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_r^2+V(r)]\psi(r)=(E+2E_F)\psi(r)$:

The book directly gives a final result $[E-2(\varepsilon_{k'}-E_F)]g_{k'}=\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}g_kV_{kk'}$, where $V_{kk'}=\Omega^{-1}\int V(r)e^{i(k'-k)r}dr$.

I'm a little lost in the details of the mathematics. Here is what I did:

I multiply an integral $\Omega^{-1}\int e^{-ik'r}d^3r$ at both sides of the Schrodinger equation, in order to use the $\delta$-function to pick out the $k'$ state, and write $\cos(kr)$ as $(e^{ikr}+e^{-ikr})/2$

$$\frac{1}{\Omega}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d^3re^{-ik'r}[-2\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla_r^2+V(r)]\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}g_k\cos(kr)
=\frac{1}{\Omega}\int_{-\infty}^\infty d^3re^{-ik'r}(E+2E_F)\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}g_k\cos (kr)$$

For the first term on the left side, I think I got the correct answer
$\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{m}\frac{1}{\Omega}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^3r(\frac{e^{i(-k'+k)r}}{2}+\frac{e^{-i(k'+k)r}}{2})g_k
=\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{m}(\frac{\delta(-k'+k)}{2}+\frac{\delta(k'+k)}{2})g_k
=\frac{\hbar^2k'^2}{m}g_{k'}
=2\varepsilon_{k'}g_{k'}$

But the second term on the left side seems to be
$\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}\frac{1}{\Omega}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^3re^{-ik'r}(\frac{e^{ikr}+e^{-ikr}}{2})V(r)g_k$

rather than
$\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}\frac{1}{\Omega}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}d^3re^{i(k-k')r}V(r)g_k=\sum\limits_{|k|>k_F}g_kV_{kk'}$.

Is there anything wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no further restraints, you could do $\vec{k} \rightarrow -\vec{k}$ in one of the sums, to show that they are equal:
\begin{equation}
\frac {1}{2} \sum_{|k|>k_F} \int_{-\infty}^\infty d^3re^{i(k^{'}+k)r} V(r) = \frac {1}{2}\sum_{|k|>k_F} \int_{-\infty}^\infty d^3re^{i(k^{'}-k)r} V(r)
\end{equation}
However, what about the degeneracy: $g_k = g_{-k}$ ?

(And you mixed up multiplying with the factors $e^{-ik^{'}r}$, in the kintetic energy term you had $e^{ik^{'}r}$)

Comment: Oh, you are right! Thank you so much. I think the $g_k$ should be degenerate with $g_{-k}$ but not quite sure. Will come back to give the answer when I finish this chapter. And thank you for correcting the mistakes!